# after run bin/magento setup:upgrade got the error

Tags: magento2, error, payment, code-generation

I've gotten this notification:

> The following modules are outdated:
>   Test_Test schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
>   Test_Test data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0

After running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` I got the error:

> [Exception]
>    Warning: file_get_contents(var/di/setup.ser): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on line 28

How can I solve this?

Comment: Deleting var/generation, var/cache and var/di solved it for me.

Answer (score 9):

Deleting var/generation, var/cache and var/di solved it for me.

Comment: Don't forget about `/var/page_cache`

Comment: I have delete `var/generation, var/cache and var/di` but issue not solved yet, tell me if you have another solution for the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your need to only delete **var/di** folder by

```
rm -rf var/di/*
```

Or delete folder manually

If still not worked delete **var/generation and var/cache** folder

> rm -rf var/generation/*
>
> rm -rf var/cache/*

Or delete folder manually

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common issue, you can find more information here. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4795

You can also try the following solution until it is fixed. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4795#issuecomment-228610110

Answer (score 0):

Run `rm -rf pub/static/*; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*; php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` instead. It clears multiple areas.